# Dolphin shows wrong size of the directory?

Tags: linux, kde, manjaro

The dolphin file manager shows 65G of storage for Secondary disk but it actually is 645G! How can i fix this?

[dolphin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcndP.png)

[lsblk output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwnLv.png)

Comment: How many gigs in just /run/media/insp (without sub-directories)?

Comment: Is Dolphin perhaps running into permission problems? It's also showing as FUSE, what's the filesystem? NTFS? // Please also provide the output of `df /run/media/insp`.

Comment: yes it is a ntfs file system.i mounted it through /etc/fstab with ntfs.

Answer (score 1):

What dolphin shows is the total size of all files in `Secondary Disk`. In other words, in the above case (i.e. in which the directory is a mountpoint), it's the current *usage* of the filesystem on `/dev/sda3` (well, more or less, metadata size might be excluded). You can / should compare it with `Used` in `df -h /run/media/insp/Secondary\ Disk`.

What `lsblk` shows is the capacity of the partition, i.e. the *maximum* size that can be used by the filesystem on it.

P.S. Btw, IIRC, `Size` in `df` is the capacity of the partition *that is currently allocated to the filesystem*, so if you have ever enlarged a partition but not the filesystem on it, it could be different from `SIZE` in `lsblk`.)

EDIT: When I take a look again at your screenshot I realize that, perhaps what you wonder is why the usage implied in `Free space` is 625.5G (`645.1` - `19.6`). In addition to `df -h`, also run `du -sh` with and without `--apparent-size` on `/run/media/insp/Secondary\ Disk` and see what they give. Perhaps there's indeed something wrong with the filesystem (which can probably, if at all, be fixed only in Windows).